# UITableView not properly overlaid by UIView

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

My aim is to display a `UIView` with a `UIActivityIndicatorView` overlaid over a `UITableView` while I'm loading the `UITableView`s future content from the web. I've added the `UIView` with it's subview to my Controller in Inteface Builder. But even when I try to bring the Activity Indicator View to the front with `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(ActivityView)` (self being the `UITableViewController`) the Table separators remain visible:

[image: separators still visible with overlaid uiview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a UITableViewController and not a UITableView inside of a UIViewController.  The difference is that the UITableViewController has the tableView as its main view and thus any subviews you add are inside the tableview, not above or below it.  In a UIViewController, the main view is just a UIView and thus you can have a tableView as a subview of that view.

```
UITableViewController view:

UITableView
   - ActivityIndicator

UIViewController with embedded TableView:

UIView
   - UITableView
   - ActivityIndicator
```

Comment: Ah. And since the seperators are part of the UITableView and not a Subview they're displayed at the very front. Got it. So using the workaround MGU suggested is just fine in this case? Or is it best practice to use a UIView as the root view? edit: I suppose I can't add any other UI elements (Controlls, etc) to this view either now, no?

Comment: If you plan on adding other controls, views, etc above, I would convert it now.

Comment: Gotcha, that's what I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the separtor:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

and display it after the data is loaded (in case you want it).

Comment: I know, but thats not really a solution, thats a workaround. And it might not just be the seperators but all elements of the table as well. Currently the table is empty.